# Is it possible to have simultaneous multiple keyboard input on a single Linux machine?

Tags: linux

Basically, I want the ability to connect one or more USB keyboards to a machine, and have each keyboard control a separate terminal emulator. Both keyboards would be in use at the same time. Mouse is not needed, x is not needed.

This may sound like a stupid idea, but it could be useful in the case where many students need to use a computer but the school does not have much money.

Thanks!

Comment: Like a mainframe?

Comment: It's actually easier *with* X.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with X and mice, multiseating will suit your needs.

[Multiseating at X.org](http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/Multiseat/)
[systemd and multiseating](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat/)
[Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Multiseat)
[Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg_multiseat)
[Gentoo](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Multiseat)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement that I wanted to have several keyboards controlling different terminals.  I did search internet a lot and I did even reach here but found no solutions.

And since I found no solution, I created [Multi Key Term](https://www.sadiqpk.org/projects/multi-keyterm.html), one such program that Just Works™ :)

I know that this question is too old, but there could still be people looking for a solution.